# Summation over an emptyset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I encountered a weird question the other day. Evaluate $\sum_{i\in\emptyset}1$? Is this zero or is it something else?

Comment: It looks like $0$ to me.

Comment: One way of thinking about this is as $0 \times 1$. The related question of the empty product is not so easy http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110546/what-is-the-product-of-the-empty-set or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017441/why-is-empty-product-defined-to-be-1. When you have divided the product by every factor, only $1$ is left.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is generally considered as a convention that sums over the empty set are equal to zero and products over the empty set are equal to one.

So you obtain, e.g.,
$$ \sum_{i \in I \cup \emptyset} a_i = \sum_{i\in I} a_i + \sum_{i \in \emptyset} a_i = \sum_{i \in I} a_i$$
for any collection of real numbers $a_i$, $i \in I$.