# Value of finite product based on empty set

Tags: products

How does one evaluate the following product if the set S happens to be empty?

\begin{aligned} f(n)= n \prod_{x \in S} \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right) \end{aligned}

Is the value simply n or is it undefined (or zero)??

Thanks.

Edit: It seems rather odd that this question has been rated off-topic for lacking context or other details.  I would have thought it rather obvious that it was about how to evaluate the product when there is no x due to an empty set.  I would have guessed undefined because one cannot assign a value to $(1-1/x)$.  However, as shown by C.Falcon, the convention is $1$.  There's no other context or missing details.  Feel free to delete if it doesn't meet the relevant standards.

Comment: This resembles the formula for [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). If it is so, then $S$ is the divisors of $n$, which cannot be empty.

Comment: Yes, I based my example on that function but my example is not intended to be defined such that S is the divisors of n.  Cheers.

Comment: See also [Why is empty product defined to be $1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017441/why-is-empty-product-defined-to-be-1) and [What is the product of the empty set?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110546/what-is-the-product-of-the-empty-set).

Comment: @kennyLau In fact, in the formula for $\varphi$ the set $S$ is set of *primies* dividing $n$, so if you want to use the formula to calculate $\varphi(1)$, you will get empty product.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Oh, my brain jammed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) is by convention equal to $1$ (the identity element for the multiplication), therefore whenever $S$ is empty, one has $f:n\mapsto n$.

Comment: It's analogous to a sum indexed by an empty set being zero (the additive identity) by convention. +1 for you.